# What are the advantages of port scanning?

Tags: ports, network-scanners

It seems like all the google results to this question answer what port scanning is, but go into little detail about how a pentester or hacker could use the information about what ports a network has open to leverage an attack on it.

Why do vulnerabilities arise by scanning and finding open ports, and what are those vulnerabilities?

Comment: I googled your question and the second result was as follows:

*"Port scanners are important to network security technicians because they can reveal possible security vulnerabilities on the targeted system."*

Pentester leverage vulnerabilities to execute an attack and gain access into a system or otherwise disrupt its normal operation. If you want to know more than this, kindly make your question more specific.

Comment: First paragraph of the wiki article on the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner

Comment: I’ve edited my question to make it less broad, but as I originally stated search results like the ones both of you cited go into little detail about how knowing which ports are open leads to a vulnerability, and therefore allows an attack to happen. Why do vulnerabilities arise by finding other open ports, and what are those vulnerabilities?

Comment: Ports never have vulnerabilities. The services running on the ports have vulnerabilities. Scanners look for ***services***, as explained by the wiki page.

Comment: Ports on a system are simply a window to allow other systems or users to communicate with that system. As schroeder said, services are running behind these ports. Examples are Web, FTP, SSH, RDP, etc. These are essentially software running as part of an OS or third-party applications. Vulnerabilities arise within software, and one can say they are an inevitable since software is written by humans, and humans make mistakes. Therefore, when you perform a port scan, you are probing for the existence of running services so as to analyse them for exploitable vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can open a locked 2000 VW Golf with a flathead screwdriver. I want to steal a car, so I walk through a car park with my screwdriver looking for Golfs. I do so by looking in each parking space.

I'm not looking ***for*** the parking spaces, I'm looking ***in*** each parking space to see if it has a 2000 VW Golf. Once I find one, I can exploit the door lock's vulnerability and unlock the car. I could wander around the parking lot in the dark and blindfolded, jamming my screwdriver into anything that feels like metal, but that's just silly.

Port scanning identifies network services running on a host so that the attacker can exploit vulnerabilities in the service. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner)) Trying to run random exploits on random ports is just silly.

Comment: Agree. Now days it's considered by many as not effective, but I wouldn't say so.
People need to provide an easy access to the box or some data, so they introduce all sorts of services on the machine. In either case, should not be over-looked.

Answer (score -2):

It allows the pen tester or hacker to know what type of vulnerability to use, as well as determine which open port would be the most efficient and least difficult to use to get the job done.  Of course, a web server will always have either port 80 or 443 open, but why attack those ports if you have a port like 23 open?  It would be easier and less hassle to attack port 23.  Every pen tester and attacker has the goal of completing the job being done, and doing it as fast as possible to leave as little trace of their digital footprint that leads back to them.

Comment: 1. "what type of vulnerability to use" --> "what type of exploit to use" 2. Why is port 23 easier? Do you mean the telnet service? Telnet can be as secure as ssh if you are attacking remotely. 3. How does your last line follow the rest of your post?

Comment: 1.  Not every exploit can utilize a specific vulnerability.  A vulnerability can have more than one exploit.  One has to know a vulnerability first.  
2.  How can telnet be as secure as SSH?
3.  It ties in with the previous few statements, where an attacker would want to get their attack plan done as efficiently as possible.  I probably forgot to add the part where they usually want to clear the server logs at the end of the attack.  No attacker would want to be connected to a server for three hours, the server owner could find the IP address and could alert the authorities.

Comment: Yes, *know* the vulnerability to *use* an exploit. Your wording is wrong as I pointed out. Telnet is not secure if you can observe the traffic when *other* people are using it. If presented it as a service to try to log into, it is just as secure as password-based SSH. Your last statement actually leaves out all the context and relevance to connect to the previous statements.